# Why does this function print out the digits in the wrong order?

Tags: c++

I can't figure out why this recursive function continues to print out the numbers in the wrong order. For instance, it prints out 4321 when it should be 1234. Could someone please help me fix this?

Thank You

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printIt(int);
//Why does this program print out the digits in the wrong order?
//See p. 10

int main()
{
   printIt(1234);
   cout << endl;
}

void printIt(int n)
{
    cout << n%10;
    if (n >= 10)
        printIt(n/10);

}
```

Comment: `cout << n%10;` after `printIt(n/10);`

Answer (score 8):

Think about it:

```
1234 % 10 = 4 // remainder of 1234 / 10 = 4
1234 / 10 (with rounding) = 123
123 % 10 = 3
123 / 10 (with rounding) = 12
12 % 10 = 2
12 / 10 (with rounding) = 1
1 % 10 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The function prints digits in the order you specified. You output at first the last digit but need to output at first the first digit in the number. I would rewrite the function the following way

```
void printIt(int n)
{
    const int base = 10;
    int digit = n % base;

    if ( n /= base ) printIt( n );

    cout << digit;
}
```